# Text block content recognition

Tags: wpf-controls

We are using Telerik automation framework integrated with visual studio. Even though we are giving correct property name for text block, We are not getting text block content for WPF application  We need to recognize text block. Could you please give the solution related to this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In xaml`<TextBlock  Name="TextBlock1">Test data</TextBlock>`
and in code`var value = TextBlock1.Text;`